# Кастомная клавиатура только для своего приложения?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, objective-c

Посмотрел доку по созданию кастомной клавиатуры.
Правильно ли я понял, что пользователь её должен разрешить сначала в настройках, чтобы ею можно было пользоваться? Или можно как-то её заюзать в своём приложении без захода в настройки на ios?

Comment: У текстовых полей ввода существует такое свойство как inputView, на котором можно нарисовать свою клавиатуру. Такая клавиатура будет исключительно для вашего приложения и будет доступна сразу без настроек.

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. Кастомную клавиатуру можно использовать только с разрешения пользователя.

Клавиатура является потенциально уязвимым местом, т.к. с помощью нее можно собирать пользовательские данные. Поэтому такие и сложности возникают.

Comment: А как тогда добавить свою клавиатуру, как делают многие приложения, для ввода цифр например? Просто оставляют текстовое поле активным и скрывают нативную клавиатуру?

Comment: @МишаЛандау Ну с точки зрения реализации можно представить что это UIView на котором размещено несколько UIButton и при нажатии на каждую кнопку происходит событие.

Comment: а в UITextField, можно скрыть нативную клавиатуру и оставить поле активным, ну, чтобы можно было выделять текст и работала экранная лупа?